# copying a row into specific cells on a template

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to paste the cells in order within the rows to a specific cell value on a template, while creating a new template sheet for each row.

Visually I want the following information:

[image: Data Tab]

to enter in the template as such:

[image: Template Tab]

What do I need to add to the below to make that happen? The row is in the order I'd like to extract, just need help organizing the script.

I have the following VBA script:

```
Sub distribute()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long, i As Integer
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To k

        Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        sh.Rows(i).Copy Range("A2")

    Next

End Sub
```

Thank you StackOverflow!!

This worked thanks to GMalc!

```
Sub distribute()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long, i As Integer
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To k
        With Worksheets("Template")
            .Cells(3,2).Value = sh.Cells(i,1).Rows()
            .Cells(3,4).Value = sh.Cells(i,2).Rows()        
            .Cells(8,4).Value = sh.Cells(i,3).Rows()
            .Cells(5,2).Value = sh.Cells(i,4).Rows()

            .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want your data below the headers in the template?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't make a difference really because the idea is to learn the concept, I'll have to roll this template out with different data anyway. But long answer short: yes please

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Sub distribute()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long, i As Integer
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To k
        With Worksheets("Template")
            .Cells(3,2).Value = sh.Cells(i,1).Rows(i)
            .Cells(3,4).Value = sh.Cells(i,2).Rows(i)        
            .Cells(8,4).Value = sh.Cells(i,3).Rows(i)
            .Cells(5,2).Value = sh.Cells(i,4).Rows(i)

            .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It works! some minor adjustments GMalc:Sub distribute()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long, i As Integer
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To k
        With Worksheets("Template")
            .Cells(3,2).Value = sh.Cells(i,1).Rows()
            .Cells(3,4).Value = sh.Cells(i,2).Rows()        
            .Cells(8,4).Value = sh.Cells(i,3).Rows()
            .Cells(5,2).Value = sh.Cells(i,4).Rows()

            .Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub

Comment: Don't forget to mark is the correct answer if it solved your problem despite the correction.